# Error Code: 1064 in stored procedure update

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using a prepared statement to execute an update query but I am getting the following error.

```
Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
```

Here is the query my prepared statement produces.

```
Declare update_table_stmt varchar(1024);
set @update_data = concat('update results_temp_tbl as t1 inner join data_temp_tbl as t2 on t2.suite_raw = t1.suite_raw set t1.`',@get_dataday,'` = ',@get_set_columns,';');
update results_temp_tbl as t1 inner join data_temp_tbl as t2 on t2.suite_raw = t1.suite_raw set     t1.`17356` = concat(t2.path,'/',t2.filename);

PREPARE update_table_stmt FROM @update_data;
EXECUTE update_table_stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE update_table_stmt;
```

If I copy the above query and run it, I get no errors.  So I am unsure of how to solve the issue

*****update****

Still getting the error. I have adjusted the code so it now prints out the following.

```
update results_temp_tbl as t1 inner join data_temp_tbl as t2 on t2.suite_raw = t1.suite_raw set t1.`17356` = t2.filepath_name;
```

Comment: Still getting the error. I have adjusted the code so it now prints out the following.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was in a loop and the id was null